# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - Angular 7 Forms

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am working on Angular 7 forms. I made built in validation to the form and that worked perfectly, but when I am going to make custom validation and made a custom function for that I am getting the error for a `userpass` field. What I am doing is, just to compare the two passwords, if their's a miss match then an error should be displayed.

**The HTML**

```js
              <form action="" method="POST" id="user-register" [formGroup]="registrationForm" (onSubmit)="registerUser(registrationForm)">
                  <div class="inInput">
                      <input type="text" id="username"  formControlName="username" [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('username').invalid && registrationForm.get('username').touched">
                      <label for="username">Type Your Name</label>
                      <!-- <small [class.d-none]="registrationForm.get('username').valid || registrationForm.get('username').untouched" class="error">Username is required !</small> -->
                    <div *ngIf="username.invalid && username.touched">
                      <small *ngIf="username.errors?.minlength" class="error">The minimum length should be 5.</small>
                      <small *ngIf="username.errors?.maxlength" class="error">The manimum length is 20 character.</small>
                      <small *ngIf="username.errors?.required" class="error">The username is required.</small>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="inInput">
                      <input type="email" id="useremail" formControlName="useremail" [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('useremail').invalid && registrationForm.get('useremail').touched">
                      <label for="useremail">Type Your Email</label>
                      <div *ngIf="useremail.invalid && useremail.touched">
                        <small *ngIf="useremail.errors?.email" class="error">Invalid Email</small>
                        <small *ngIf="useremail.errors?.required" class="error">The username is required.</small>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inInput">
                      <input type="password" id="userpass" formControlName="userpass" [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userpass').invalid && registrationForm.get('userpass').touched">
                      <label for="userpass">Type Your Password</label>
                      <div *ngIf="userpass.invalid && userpass.touched">
                        <small *ngIf="userpass.errors?.minlength" class="error">The minimum length should be 5.</small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass.errors?.passwordpattern" class="error">Password cannot be {{userpass.errors?.passwordpattern.value}}.</small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass.errors?.mismatch" class="error"> Passwords doesn't match. </small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass.errors?.required" class="error">The username is required.</small>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inInput">
                      <input type="password" id="userpass2" formControlName="userpass2" [class.is-invalid]="registrationForm.get('userpass2').invalid && registrationForm.get('userpass2').touched">
                      <label for="userpass2">Re-Type Your Password</label>
                      <div *ngIf="userpass2.invalid && userpass2.touched">
                        <small *ngIf="userpass2.errors?.minlength" class="error">The minimum length should be 5.</small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass2.errors?.passwordpattern" class="error">Password cannot be {{userpass.errors?.passwordpattern.value}}.</small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass2.errors?.mismatch" class="error"> Passwords doesn't match. </small>
                        <small *ngIf="userpass2.errors?.required" class="error">The username is required.</small>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-register-submit">
                      <button type="submit" class="inBtn inBtn-info"> Register Now ! </button>
                  </div>
              </form>
```

**The register.ts code**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { passWordValidation, passwordCompare } from '../globals/validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}

  get username(){ return this.registrationForm.get('username'); }
  get useremail(){ return this.registrationForm.get('useremail'); }
  get userpass(){ return this.registrationForm.get('userpass'); }
  get userpass2(){ return this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'); }

  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    username : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    useremail : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    userpass : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpas2'))]],
    userpass2 : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'))]]
  })




  


}
```

**The validators.ts code**

```js
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function passWordValidation(control : AbstractControl):{[key:string]:any} | false{
    const forbidden = /admin/.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'passwordpattern': {value:control.value}} : false;
}

//Compare the inputs
export function passwordCompare(userpass: AbstractControl , userpass2 : AbstractControl): ValidatorFn{
    return (): null | {[key:string]:any} => {
        return ((userpass.value == userpass2.value) && (userpass2.value == userpass.value)) ? null : {'mismatch': true} ;
    }
}
```

> the first function works perfectly in `validators.ts`, but I don't know whats wrong with the second one. When I remove the `passwordCompare()` from `register.ts` then I get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot add a comment as my reputation is below 50, what i found in your code is, i guess you have made a small spelling mistake:

```
userpass : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpas2'))]],
    userpass2 : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'))]]
```

it should be:

```
userpass : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'))]],
    userpass2 : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), passWordValidation, passwordCompare(this.registrationForm.get('userpass'), this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'))]]
```

you have made this.registrationForm.get('userpass2'))]] as this.registrationForm.get('userpas2'))]]

Comment: I looked after that, that's not the problem.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad okay, i will deeply look into yourcode

Comment: @NadeemAhmad have you tried using compare validators only for the 2nd password field? (re-entered password)

Comment: @NadeemAhmad yes, you need to compare only one field with another

Comment: @NadeemAhmad did you?

Comment: So how could I pass the control of both to the factory function ?

Comment: @NadeemAhmad try it once, let me know what happens